# How to add separate lines to mplfinance plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

### TL;DR

Is there any way to add separate lines to an `mplfinance` plot, like the image below, to show how a trade went?
I know how to add points, but I can't figure out how to add separate lines.

[image]

### Replication

Say you have a `pandas` dataframe that looks like this:

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20190608 | 9586.35 | 9586 | 9586 | 9586.35 |
| 20190609 | 9586.35 | 9586 | 9586 | 9586.35 |
| 20190610 | 9586.35 | 9586 | 9586 | 9586.35 |
| 20190611 | 9586.35 | 9586 | 9586 | 9586.35 |
| 20190612 | 9586.35 | 9586 | 9586 | 9586.35 |
| 20190701 | 9595.94 | 9873 | 9596 | 9674.55 |
| 20190702 | 9588.27 | 9692 | 9556 | 9576.77 |

Using `mplfinance` it's possible to plot and save an OHLC chart with something like this where `df` is the said dataframe:

```py
import mplfinance as mpf

# plot
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(
    df, type="candle", style='yahoo', ylabel='',
    xrotation=30, returnfig=True, figsize=(6,4))
# save
fig.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight',
    pad_inches=0.1, dpi=96, transparent='True')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additional lines include a vertical line, a horizontal line, a line connecting two or more pairs of dates and prices, and a trend line. Here is an example of simply drawing a line with date and price. Please refer to this page for more [details](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb).

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import mplfinance as mpf

import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-01-01", end="2021-07-01")

two_points = [('2021-06-04', 128),('2021-06-30', 138)]
mpf.plot(data, figratio=(8,4), type='candle', alines=two_points, volume=True, mav=(5, 25), style='yahoo')
```

[image]